# regular expression with condtional boundary?

Tags: python, regex

**Background**

The background of my question: to find all `mA` unit in all upper/lower case. To prompt the user as much surrounding chacracters as possible where it is mis-used as ma/Ma/MA, so that user can search and locate easily.

As we know `mA` is a valid unit used for electrical current. To be simple we only use integer number, so every line in the text

```
case 1, only number and unit: 1mA
case 2, number and unit, space: 1mA current
case 3, number and unit, punctuation: 1mA,
case 4, number and unit, Unicode characters: 1mA电流I
```

is a valid expression.

But

```
case 5, 1mAcurrent
```

should be an invalid expression since no English letters are allowed to follow the unit without space

**My regular expression trying**

So what is the correct regular expression in this situation? I have used every line in the following text

```
case 5 is taken as a right one, this is wrong      \d{1,}mA
case 4 is ignored                                  \d{1,}mA\b
case 4 is ignored                                  \d{1,}mA[^a-zA-Z]*\b
```

as you have read, none is correct.

**My complex code**

This the python code I am using, you will find I use python's `if-else`

```
import re
text = '''
case 1, only number and unit: 1mA
case 2, number and unit, space: 2mA current
case 3, number and unit, punctuation: 3mA,
case 4, number and unit, Unicode characters: 4mA电流I   
case 5, 5mAcurrent
'''
lst = text.split('\n')
lst = [i for i in lst if i]

pattern = r'(?P<QUANTITY>\d{1,}mA)(?P<TAIL>.{0,5})'

for text in lst:
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):    
        if not re.match('[a-zA-Z]', match.group('TAIL')): # extra line
            print(match.group('QUANTITY'), ', ', match.group('TAIL'))
```

which outputs

```
1mA ,  
2mA ,   curr
3mA ,  ,
4mA ,  电流I
```

obviously, bad expression `case 5, 5mAcurrent` is not been taken into account as I expected

**Ask for help**

is there an easy way to implement it in **one** regular expression pattern? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492933/regular-expression-to-match-boundary-between-different-unicode-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead just after the unit, that will check if there no alpha:

```
pattern = r'(?P<QUANTITY>\d+mA)(?![a-z])(?P<TAIL>.{0,5})'
#                       here __^^^^^^^^^
```

**Code:**

```
pattern = r'(?P<QUANTITY>\d+mA)(?![a-z])(?P<TAIL>.{0,5})'

for text in lst:
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):    
        print(match.group('QUANTITY'), match.group('TAIL'))
```

Comment: thanks, it solves my case 1-5. Today, I met case 6 "case 6, 6mA to 7mA". In all case 1-6, `number + unit` is first class, so I do hope that "6mA to " and "7mA" are matched. Is it possible?

Comment: The background of my question: to find all `mA` unit in all upper/lower case. To prompt the user as much surrounding chacracters as possible where it is mis-used as `ma/Ma/MA`, so that user can search and locate easily.

Comment: @oyster: If you have only twice value+unit, you can do: `(?P<QUANTITY>\d+mA)(?![a-z])(?:.+?(?P<QUANTITY2>\d+mA)(?![a-z]))*(?P<TAIL>.{0,5})`. If you want to match case insensitive, add `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex: `(?i)(?P<QUANTITY>\d+mA)(?![a-z])(?:.+?(?P<QUANTITY2>\d+mA)(?![a-z]))*(?P<TAIL>.{0,5})`

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a regex search with the following pattern:

```
\d+mA(?= |current|电流I|,|$)
```

This would match e.g. `1mA` followed by either a space, the word `current`, the Chinese term `电流I`, comma, or the end of the input.

```
input = "Here 1mA also 2mAcurrent and 3mA电流I and 4mA, and also 5mA"
matches = re.findall(r'\d+mA(?= |current|电流I|,|$)', input)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['1mA', '2mA', '3mA', '4mA', '5mA']
```

Comment: "current|电流I|," are all samples. If I can enumerate all the case like this, I think I can do not use regular expression . What about "5mA stable current" which follows the rule "there is a space behind the unit, so it is valid".

Comment: @oyster But my pattern would already be picking up on `5mA stable current`.  You only need to list the strings which might be directly adjoined to the end of `5mA`, with no space in between.

Comment: We can't list which English/Chinese words are allowed because there are unlimited possiblity

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = r'(?P<value>\d+)(?P<units>mA)(\S+|)'
text = ['1mA','1mA电流I','1mA,','1mAcurrent']

for i,j in enumerate(text):
    match = re.match(pattern,j)
    if match:
        print("Text "+match[0]+" matches with value:"+match['value']+ 
        ' Units:'+match['units'])
```

The above code matches all cases and uses named groups to make callable sections. There are 3 groups; I named the first 2 (values and units)

You can expand the units to any other units of interest with pipe separation. `\d+` for value matches any integer

Comment: The 3rd grouping of \S+ matches non space characters (any length) this can match current in english or kanji, or voltage etc. It also hits on the comma.

Comment: That's equivalent to `\S*` which is to say no boundary is fine, too. I understand the OP wants to avoid 2mAcurrent.

Comment: So we do not want to hit on the 4th item in the list.

Comment: Case 1~4 should be recognized as valid physical quantity (there is number and unit) expression; Case 5 should not be matched since it is not a valid physical quantity expression. However you code think case 5 is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, we might just want to collect our desired digits, followed by optional spaces, and a `mA`, which this simple expression might do so:

```
([0-9]+)(\s+)?(?=mA)
```

I'm not sure about technicalities, but if we would have float numbers this `([0-9]+)` would also change to `([0-9.]+)`. At the end, we would append a `mA` to all captured outputs.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mMulCm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = r'(?P<value>\d+)(?P<units>mA)(\s[a-z]+|[\s,]|$)'
pattern2 = r'(?P<value>\d+)(?P<units>mA)([^a-z]\S+)'
text = ['1mA','5mA电流I','1mA,','1mAcurrent','1mA current']

for i,j in enumerate(text):
    match = re.match(pattern,j)
    print(j)
    if match:
        print("Text "+match[0]+" matches with value:"+match['value']+ ' 
        Units:'+match['units'])
    else:
        match = re.match(pattern2,j)
        if match:
            print("Text "+match[0]+" matches with value:"+match['value']+ ' 
            Units:'+match['units'])
```

This solution ignores Case 5. Using 2 patterns and an else statement when we do not return a match on the first pattern.